# Apache Spark - NoSuchMethodError SparkContext.assertNoStopped()

Tags: java, maven, exception, apache-spark

If I try to run the jar I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.SparkContext.assertNotStopped()V
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.<init>(SparkSession.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:837)
    at com.tproj.testing.sparkTest.App.main(App.java:25)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

And i dont know why... I build with maven and added `spark-core_2.10` with version 2.0.0 and `spark-sql_2.10` with version 2.0.0

And my main method looks like:

```
  public static void main (String[] args) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty ("user", USER);
    prop.setProperty ("password", PASSWORD);

    SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder ().master ("local").appName ("spark").getOrCreate ();

    Dataset<Row> data = session.read ().jdbc (URL, "T_USER", prop);
    data.select ("theid", "thename")
    .filter (data.col ("thename").startsWith ("E")).show();
  }
```

I don't understand why the problem comes...

Comment: Did you find any solution of this problem ?

Comment: No (10 more to go)